# удаление строки, которая содержит определённый элемент

Tags: python

Есть файл с таким содержимым:

```
type teei_daemon_exec, fs_type, sysfs_type;
type nvram_daemon_exec, fs_type, sysfs_type;
type system_sensor_data_file, data_file_type, file_type;
type sysenv_daemon_exec, fs_type, sysfs_type;
type mobicore_data_file, data_file_type, file_type;
type idd_data_file, data_file_type, file_type;
type qns_file, file_type;
```

Нужно удалить строки, которые имеют в себе `_exec` чтобы остались:

```
type system_sensor_data_file, data_file_type, file_type;
type mobicore_data_file, data_file_type, file_type;
type idd_data_file, data_file_type, file_type;
type qns_file, file_type;
```

В сети видел много разных способов, но они почему-то не подошли. 
Есть какой-то простой способ это реализовать?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lines = []
with open('file.txt') as fh:
    lines = fh.readlines()

with open('file.txt', 'w') as fh:
    fh.writelines(i for i in lines if '_exec' not in i)
```

Comment: Я не правильно поставил цель.. обновил вопрос

Comment: Исправил ответ.